# Odoo 14 how to add multi-levels to a tree view

Tags: treeview, odoo, odoo-14

I don't really know if what I am trying to do is possible. how to create multi-levels in the tree view like grouping which allows you to  drill down the task tree
the closest thing I found was the search panel but it can't handle the large amount of tasks (530)

- Parent Task A

  - sub-Task 1

    - sub-sub-Task 1.1
    - sub-sub-Task 1.2
  - sub-Task 2

    - sub-sub-Task 2.1